# Output of CNN should be image

Tags: pytorch

I am pretty new to deep learning, so I got one question:

Assume an input Grayscale image of shape (128,128,1). Target (Output) is as well an (128,128,1) sized image, e.g. for segmentation, depth prediction etc.. Usually with valid padding the size of the image shrinks after several convolution layers.

What are decent (maybe not the toughest one) variants to keep the size or predict a same sized image? Is it via same-padding? Is it via tranpose convolution or upsampling? Should I use a FCN at the end and reshape them to the image size? I am using pytorch. I would be glad for any hints, because I didn't find much in the internet.

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR;** You want to look at [Deconv networks](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers) (Convolution transpose) that help regenerate an image using convolution operations. You want to build an encoder-decoder convolution architecture that compresses an image to a latent representation using convolutions and then decodes an image from this compressed representation. For image segmentation, a popular architecture is `U-net`.

---

**NOTE:** I cant answer for pytorch, so I will he sharing the Tensorflow equivalent. Please feel to ignore the code, but since you are looking for the concept, I can help you with what you need to solve this.

You are trying to generate an image as the output of the network.

A series convolution operation help to `Downsample` an image. Since you need an output 2D matrix (gray scale image), you want to `Upsample` as well. Such a network is called a Deconv network.

The first series of layers convolve over the input, 'flattening' them into a vector of channels. The next set of layers use `2D Conv Transpose` or `Deconv` operations to change the channels back into a 2D matrix (Gray scale image)

Refer to this image for reference -

[image]

Here is a sample code that shows you how you can take a (10,3,1) image to a (12,10,1) image using a deconv net.

> You can find the `conv2dtranspose` layer implementation in pytorch [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.ConvTranspose2d.html).

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils

inp = layers.Input((128,128,1))  ##
x = layers.Conv2D(2, (3,3))(inp) ##  Convolution part
x = layers.Conv2D(4, (3,3))(x)   ##
x = layers.Conv2D(6, (3,3))(x)   ##

##########

x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(6, (3,3))(x)
x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(4, (3,3))(x)   ##   ##  Deconvolution part
out = layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (3,3))(x) ##

model = Model(inp, out)
utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=False)
```

[image]

---

Also, if you are looking for tried and tested architectures in this domain, check out `U-net`; [U-Net: Convolutional Networks for Biomedical Image Segmentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597). This is an `encoder-decoder (conv2d, conv2d-transpose)` architecture that uses a concept called `skip connections` to avoid information loss and generate better image segmentation masks.

[image]